# Which Internet Explorer quirks should web developers be aware of?

Tags: internet-explorer

Older versions of Internet Explorer are being phased out, but they will stick around. Which of their quirks should a web developer have in mind when coding a website in order to avoid major breakage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty good overview

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/9-most-common-ie-bugs-and-how-to-fix-them/